# Vectorized Matrix-Vector multiplication along specified axis of multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, vectorization

Suppose I have an array A of size (M,N,D,D) and a vector x of size (M,N,D). I want to produce the array b of size (M,N,D) where b[m,n,:] = np.matmul(A[m,n,:,:],x[m,n,:]). So basically, the D-by-D matrix contained in A[m,n,:] and the vector of size D contained in x[m,n,:] should be multiplied together following standard matrix-vector multiplication. A naive for-loop implementation would be

```
for m in range(M):
    for n in range(N):
        b[m,n,:] = np.matmul(A[m,n,:],x[m,n,:])
```

Obviously this is inefficient for large N and M (which is the case for me; N is of the order of 100,000 and M is of the order of 1000). My question is: How to vectorize this loop? I've tried using np.tensordot but I keep getting shape mismatches no matter how I try to structure it, presumably because A has 4 axes whereas x has 3 (Note that for all I know, np.tensordot **is** the right function to use, I'm just not using it correctly)

**EDIT**
Tried using np.einsum, but I don't get the expected result (which should be [5,11]:
[image]

Comment: `np.matmul(A[m,n,:,:],x[m,n,:])`does the sum-of-products on the last dimension of both array, where `x[m,n,:]` is 1d, and is handled by (according to the docs) as `x[m,n,:,None]` (2nd to the last).  The key `matmul` concept is "Last of A with 2nd to the last of B".  The leading dimensions, here `m,n` are 'batch' ones.  (`tensordot` does not handle 'batches').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where `np.einsum` shines:

```
np.einsum('mnij,mnj->mni', A,B)
```

Check with

```
np.allclose(np.einsum('mnij,mnj->mni', A,x), b)
```

returns `True`

Comment: I tried this; while the end-result has the correct shape, it does not produce the correct output. Consider the case A[0,0,:] = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) and x[0,0,:] = np.array([1,2]). In this case, I would expect b[0,0,:] = np.array([5,11]), since this is the matrix-vector product. However, running b = np.einsum('mndd,mnd->mnd',A,x) reveals that b[0,0,:] = np.array([1,8]).

Comment: @torola you should double check the code. I got `[5, 11]` on my system.

Comment: I've edited the original post to show my output- could the error be due to how I'm assigning values to A and/or x?

Comment: @torola my formula is `'mnij,mnj->mni'`, not `mndd,mnd->mnd`, which is the trace formula.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense now (I thought the i and j you used were just placeholders and that I should replace them with d). It works perfectly now, Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The same result can be achieved with broadcasting:

```
x1 = x.reshape(M,N,d,1)
b1 = np.matmul(A,x1)
b2 = b1.reshape(M,N,d)
```