# Matrix multiplication along axis (instead of for loop)

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a better way of doing the following:

```
[W.T[i,:] @ Sigma @ W[:,i] for i in range(W.shape[1])]
```

Where, `Sigma.shape = (n,n)` and `W.shape = (n, m)`

I've been trying to take advantage of `np.matmul` or `np.dot` but it seems these are not made to do what I need. I have also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69741946/vectorized-matrix-vector-multiplication-along-specified-axis-of-multidimensional), but I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you are looking for is

```py
np.einsum('ij,jk,ki->i', W.T, Sigma, W)
# or 
np.einsum('ji,jk,ki->i', W, Sigma, W)
```

benchmark

```py
import numpy as np
n = 5
m = 3
np.random.seed(0)
W = np.random.rand(n, m)
Sigma = np.random.rand(n, n)

res1 = [W.T[i,:] @ Sigma @ W[:,i] for i in range(W.shape[1])]
res2 = np.einsum('ji,jk,ki->i', W, Sigma, W)

assert all([np.isclose(x, y) for x, y in zip(res1, res2)])
```

basically a matrix multiplication is done by

```py
A @ B
np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
```

the second matrix multiplication is simply `ik,ki->i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [148]: Sigma = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2); W = np.arange(10,16).reshape(2,3)

In [149]: [W.T[i,:] @ Sigma @ W[:,i] for i in range(W.shape[1])]
Out[149]: [1426, 1675, 1944]
```

Your iteration can be rewritten as:

```
In [150]: [W.T[i,:] @ Sigma @ W.T[i,:] for i in range(W.shape[1])]
Out[150]: [1426, 1675, 1944]
```

That makes it clearer that the first dimension of `W.T` is the "batch" one.  For `matmul`, that should be first of 3, so we can do:

```
In [151]: W.T[:,None,:] @ Sigma @ W.T[:,:,None]  # (m,1,n)@(n,n)@(m,n,1)=>(m,1,1)
Out[151]: 
array([[[1426]],

       [[1675]],

       [[1944]]])
```

and then squeeze out the extra size 1 dimensions:

```
In [152]: _.squeeze()
Out[152]: array([1426, 1675, 1944])
```

In the equivalent einsum, 'i' is the batch dimension that's passed through to the result, while 'j' and 'k' are the two sum-of-products dimensions.

```
In [156]: np.einsum('ji,jk,ki->i',W,Sigma,W)
Out[156]: array([1426, 1675, 1944])
```